# How do I automate the substitution of assigned inbound rules with public IP addresses within and across security groups in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-security-group

My current setup on EC2 Management Console involves:

- multiple security groups representing various resources on AWS
- multiple inbound rules within a security group representing people's public IP addresses that are whitelisted to access the resource

Currently, when a person's public IP address changes because of ISP issues, I have to manually go into EC2MC and change the inbound rule associated with that person to allow them access. There are multiple inbound rules within a security group and multiple security groups that this person is whitelisted for. Rather than changing, for instance, 9 rules manually, I'm wondering if there's a way to launch a script that prompts for the security group name, person's name, and new IP address so that this substitution occurs automatically?

[Example layout of security groups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOdRE.png)

[Example layout of inbound rules within a security group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Fnur.png)

Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty straightforward script to write.  AWS has an CLI/API for `authorize-security-group-ingress` and `revoke-security-group-ingress`.  You could do this a Bash script or any language with an AWS SDK.  The revocation would be easier if you know their previous IP address, otherwise you may need to make a `describe-security-groups` call to determine it based on descriptions.

Below are links to the relevant CLI docs:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/authorize-security-group-ingress.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/revoke-security-group-ingress.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-security-groups.html

Answer (score 0):

You can automate this task using bash or python script. You will just have to run the AWS SDK commands for adding/updating the inbound rules on particular security group.

e.g. For updating public IP of one of your existing SSH user:

```
aws ec2 modify-security-group-rules --group-id sg-xxxxxxxxxx --security-group-rules "SecurityGroupRuleId=sgr-xxxxxxxxxxx,SecurityGroupRule={Description=User1,IpProtocol=TCP,FromPort=22,ToPort=22,CidrIpv4=101.10.0.0/32}"
```

For this, you first need to know your security group id & security group rule id which you are going to update. Then you can replace them dynamically into above command.